# Class function error C++

Tags: c++

I have 3 classes, lets say ClassA, ClassB and Validator.  I want to pass one variable of both classA and classB to the Validator, which will compare the values, and return a string result.  I get the following error: error:

request for member ‘compareValues’ in ‘validatorObject’, which is of non-class type ‘Validator*’

**main.cpp**

```
cout << classAobject.compareValues(computer1->getValue(), classBobject->getValue());
```

**validator.cpp**

```
string Validator::compareValues(string classAvalue, string classBValue) {
if (classAvalue == "R") {
    if (classBvalue == "R") {
        return "Equal";
    }
}
// More will go in this function - just want to get it working first
```

}

**validator.h**

```
string compareValues(string classAvalue, string classBValue);
```

Comment: Where do you declare `classAobject`?

Comment: I'm assuming that compareValues is declared inside class Validator.(otherwise you have an another unrelated problem)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error appear because you need to access class member from pointer to class by using `->` operator: `cout << classAobject->compareValues(.....)`

`Foo->bar()` is equivalent to `(*Foo).bar()`, and `Foo->baz` is equivalent to `(*Foo).baz`

Comment: The Validator must compare the values from both classA and classB.  compareValues is a function of the Validator class.

Comment: I'm assuming classAobject is of type `Validator`, otherwise the problem must be on another line

Comment: No, classAobject is of type ClassA.  I have got rid of that error by swapping the '.' for the '->' but now I have a seg fault :(

Comment: Well, you need to find where you an object `Validator*` (pointer to `Validator`) with `.` operator. (And maybe you need to replace classAObject with something else, but this is unrelated)